# Missing Tap-Jacking protection for Flutter apps for both Android and iOS

Tags: flutter

I have built an App using flutter SDK, I want to enable Tap-Jacking protection for my app so that no other overlying app gets access to the loop holes for accessing the confidential data.

How to do this for apps build with Flutter?